# Android AutoSync Run interval?

Tags: android, synchronization

Does anyone know that when you have autosync enabled, how frequently are the google accounts synced for various apps? I know its almost instantaneous for Gmail but what about other things?
e.g. if I have a Picasa app that uses [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) to sync local photos with online, how frequently the [onPerformSync](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html#onPerformSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentProviderClient,%20android.content.SyncResult%29) method will be called?

Also, can this interval be overridden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoSync will be triggered on change in DataSources.

Eg. If you have a Contacts SyncAdapter which is configured for automatic sync then onPerformSync will be called when there is a change in Contacts after a delay of 30s.

Comment: I also eventually figured out it is 30s. Can I change this interval to something higher ?

Comment: It seems we cannot configure it. I spent sometime looking into AccountManager apis, I couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I found another work around to configure this delay(This might result in other side effects, check below step carefully)

This is by using combination of ContentObserver and AccountManager api. Below are the steps:

1. Register a ContentObserver to the Contacts DB.
2. On any change in Contacts db, onChange of your contentObserver will be triggered. Inside this function cancel the pending syncRequests like below. `ContentResolver.cancelSync(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY);
3. Now schedule the Sync as per required delay.

The above will have side effect of ensuring ContentObserver to be alive all the time and it is not recommended.